# Add attributes to FOSUserBundle in Symfony 2 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've installed the FOSUserBundle on Symfony 2 for MongoDB and I would like to add some custom fields but they are always empty.

My UserBundle:

```
<?php
namespace Skurty\UserBundle\Document;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *     collection="user"
 * )
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $test;

    public function setTest($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function getTest()
    {
        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

A controller (not in the same bundle that the UserBundle):

```
$user = $this->getUser();

// or

$user = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getRepository('SkurtyUserBundle:User')
    ->find(new \MongoId('...'));

// $user->getUsername() => 'skurty'
// $user->getTest() => null
```

And the MongoDB document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "username" : "skurty", /* FOSUserBundle fields */, "test" : "abc" }
```

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: did you clear your cache? This might be a result-cache issue.

Comment: It was that and I totally forgot to look at it (I only updated the mongodb schema)... So problem solved, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your database schema and **clear your cache** for the changes to take effect.

Otherwise you may end up receiving cached results that don't reflect the current data in the database.